# Confused about basic state and props in React

Tags: reactjs

Let's suppose I have two components i.e. "Parent" which contains two state variables and a child "Child" to which these two variables are passed.

```
export default function Parent() {
  const [a, setA] = React.useState(1);
  const [b, setB] = React.useState(2);

  const inc = () => {
    setA(a + 1);
    setB(b + 1);
  }

  return (
    <div>
      <Child a={a} b={b} />
      <button onClick={inc}>Inc</button>
    </div>
  );
}
```

```
export function Child({ a, b }) {
  console.log(a, b);
  const [inA, setInA] = React.useState(a || -1);
  const [inB, setInB] = React.useState(b || -1);

  return (
    <div>
      <div>{inA}</div>
      <div>{inB}</div>
    </div>
  );
}
```

My understanding was that as soon as the props passed on to `Child` are changed it will re-render and hence both `inA` and `inB` will get newer defaults but it does not happen. Why is that?

Relevant Stackblitz [link](https://stackblitz.com/edit/react-ts-m19lu8?file=Children.tsx).

Comment: State is tied to the [position in the tree](https://beta.reactjs.org/learn/preserving-and-resetting-state#state-is-tied-to-a-position-in-the-tree), it will add some more context to the behaviour, only state change in parent does not change the state in children, but causese them to rerender

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> My understanding was that as soon as the props passed on to Child are
> changed it will re-render and hence both inA and inB will get newer
> defaults

Yes, it will re-render but `inA` & `inB` don't reinitialize with new props. Note that the first argument you pass to `useState` is only used once for the first initialization of the state. After that, your useState will keep the current state across the re-renders and will update it when you call `setInA` or `setInB`

Comment: this.
+ i'd pass down the `inc` function down to the Child component and handle the increment of `inA` and `inB` directly, instead of re-rendering.